# Redirect Server IP subdirectory to Hostname in .htaccess file on apache

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect my server IP to my hostname using mod_rewrite on my WordPress `.htaccess` file.

This is what I've tried -

```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^X\.XXX\.XXX\.XX$
    RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
  </IfModule>
```

This works fine if I visit the IP address directly but if I visit the IP with a subdirectory path it does not redirect.

For example:

```
IP XX.XX.XX.XX - Redirects fine
IP XX.XX.XX.XX/phpmyadmin - NO redirection
```

Anyone have any idea what is wrong with my query. Any help is appreciated.

---

**UPDATE:**

Here is my `.htaccess` file having implemented the solution from @MrWhite, but it's still not working.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.XXXX.co.uk
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.XXXX.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]



# BEGIN WP Security
#AIOWPS_BASIC_HTACCESS_RULES_START
<Files .htaccess>
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>
ServerSignature Off
LimitRequestBody 10485760
<Files wp-config.php>
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>
#AIOWPS_BASIC_HTACCESS_RULES_END
#AIOWPS_DISABLE_INDEX_VIEWS_START
Options -Indexes
#AIOWPS_DISABLE_INDEX_VIEWS_END
# END WP Security

#AIOWPS_BASIC_HTACCESS_RULES_END
# END WP Security

# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

Options -Indexes
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include your complete `.htaccess` file with these directives in place.

Comment: _"Here is my htaccess file"_ - why would that still _need_ such an explicit redirect based on the IP address, when you already got `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.XXXX.co.uk` plus a corresponding RewriteRule at the very top? Is `www.XXXX.co.uk` not "your hostname" that you want to rewrite the requests with IP address to, or what exactly is the situation?

Comment: @CBroe Because that's the alternative solution having followed the suggestion in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

> This works fine if i visit the IP address directly but if i visit the IP with a sub directory path it does not redirect.

This sounds like you've put the directives in the wrong place. If you've put the rule at the end of the file, after the WordPress code block then your redirect will only be triggered for requests to the document root (the homepage) since the WP code block effectively ignores any request for the homepage itself (since mod_dir triggers the subrequest for `index.php` - the WP front-controller).

However, any request for a "sub directory", ie. a virtual URL-path, will be routed to the WP front-controller before your rule has a chance to be triggered.

You need to move your rule to the top of the file, importantly *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` code block.

You do not need the `<IfModule>` wrapper and you do not need to repeat the `RewriteEngine On` directive, since this will already occur later in the file inside the WP code block.

---

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^X\.XXX\.XXX\.XX$
> RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
> ```

Instead of checking that the requested hostname is the IP address, you could instead check that the requested hostname is *not* your canonical hostname. You will catch requests for non-www (or www) as well and you are not tied to an IP address.

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The `!` prefix on the *CondPattern* negates the expression. The `=` operator makes this a lexicographic string comparison, not a regex. So no need to backslash-escape the literal dots. (This would also make it easier to match IP addresses, eg. `=203.0.113.111`.)

Comment: I have tried your second option but it still does not redirect. I have added my full htaccess code to this post for reference.

Comment: @user36319 Make sure you've cleared your browser (and any intermediary) caches. To clarify, the subdirectory path you are requesting is not a physical subdirectory that (by chance) has it's own `.htaccess` file? Otherwise, this really should work for any URL-path, providing a request for the IP address is actually resolving to your site (but it must be if the homepage is being redirected by this rule).

Comment: @user36319 Were you putting the redirect rule in the wrong place before (ie. at the end of the file)?

Comment: @user36319 `/phpmyadmin` could be a "special" directory that you don't have direct control over. Does this directory actually exist in the public HTML space?

Comment: Thanks guys finally i managed to get it working i had to restart the server and clear all caches. It works as intended now. @user36319 I have removed Phpmyadmin from the server and that fixed that issue too.

Comment: @user36319 If this helped answer your question then please mark it as "accepted" and consider upvoting answers you find helpful. Thanks, much appreciated.